# Visual Studio 2012 C++ platform toolsets missing

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I have Visual Studio 2008 installed on my machine and now installed VS2012. In the C++-project-settings of VS2012 I should now be able to change the platform toolset back to VC++2008 (V90), but there's only the new version VC++2012 (V110) available. Does anybody know the reason why my old installation of VS2008 is not recognized or how I can manually add the old platform toolset?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The v90 platform toolset is part of VS 2010, so you must install both VS 2008 and VS 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Well i have no experience with 2012, but when i used 2010 and 2008 combined i just had two different program files folders and so two different executable to start visual studio in the version i liked. Maybe this is of help to you just make 2 shortcuts ?

Comment: It is installed in 2 different directories and I can indeed use them separately. But there is this possibility to use only the newer version with the old platform tools, so I'd prefer that way.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure you've got your VC2008 environment variables set properly, you can always hand-edit the `.vcxproj`.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|Win32'" Label="Configuration">
   <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
   <ConfigurationType>StaticLibrary</ConfigurationType>
   <PlatformToolset>v110</PlatformToolset>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Just change the `v110` to `v90`.

Obviously, that is kind of a hack. The `v90` option should be there in the project properties. If this doesn't work, you could try reinstalling or repairing the 2008 install.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I assume it would if in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild there would be all the config files for the different toolsets. But then I could select it in the project-settings also :) The problem is that these files are missing there and I can't just manually reproduce them. Also copying them from a computer where the same combination of VS-installations work as intended doesn't help because I don't know how to edit those files to fit my installations.

Comment: Did you install 2008 *after* 2012? Maybe that's why.

Comment: Or maybe it's a bug? I've got 2008, 2010, and 2012 installed, and it works fine. I've never tried it without 2010 installed. Maybe it stops searching once it determines it can't find the `v100` toolset.

Comment: I installed VS2012 after VS2008. Maybe I should try to reinstall VS2008 again.